# brick hill server hosting error when trying to use quickdb

Tags: node.js

i use a server that uses nodejs (for the game brick hill)
and i try installing quickdb and putting the quick modules in the start js file
but it keeps erroring of not finding fs module. i put the module everywhere, i cleared my cache, and its a vm error

my code in a js file (userscript)

```
const { QuickDB } = require("quick.db");
const db = new QuickDB();
```

this triggers a error and i put fs in the script and it still errors

```
<< PostServer: true | Port: 42480 | Map: example.brk >>
[*] Loaded Core Script: admin.js
[*] Loaded Core Script: bubbleChat.js
[*] Loaded Core Script: chatUtils.js
[*] Loaded Core Script: cli.js
VMError: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\wip\node-hill-template\node_modules/fs'
    at CustomResolver.loadAsPackage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\wip\node-hill-template\node_modules\vm2\lib\resolver.js:427:11)
    at CustomResolver.loadAsDirectory (C:\Users\User\Desktop\wip\node-hill-template\node_modules\vm2\lib\resolver.js:439:15)
    at CustomResolver.loadNodeModules (C:\Users\User\Desktop\wip\node-hill-template\node_modules\vm2\lib\resolver.js:457:13)
    at CustomResolver.resolveFull (C:\Users\User\Desktop\wip\node-hill-template\node_modules\vm2\lib\resolver.js:310:12)
    at CustomResolver.resolve (C:\Users\User\Desktop\wip\node-hill-template\node_modules\vm2\lib\resolver.js:121:15)
    at resolve (C:\Users\User\Desktop\wip\node-hill-template\node_modules\vm2\lib\nodevm.js:317:21)
    at VM2 Wrapper.apply (C:\Users\User\Desktop\wip\node-hill-template\node_modules\vm2\lib/bridge.js:485:11)
    at requireImpl (C:\Users\User\Desktop\wip\node-hill-template\node_modules\vm2\lib/setup-node-sandbox.js:90:19)
    at require (C:\Users\User\Desktop\wip\node-hill-template\node_modules\vm2\lib/setup-node-sandbox.js:171:10)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\wip\node-hill-template\node_modules\quick.db\out\drivers\JSONDriver.js:5:14
[*] Loaded Core Script: coreMethods.js
[*] Loaded Core Script: respawn.js
[*] Loaded Core Script: teamSpawn.js
[*] Loaded Core Script: toolHandler.js
[*] Error loading User Script: tools.js
Listening on port: 42480.
Running server locally.
cli>
```

i tried clearing cache, put fs everywhere, delete node modules, install latest versions of quick db and fs.

Comment: How are you running this?  `fs` is built into Node.js, so it seems like you're using something other than Node, or using something sandboxed.

Comment: @brad im using the template and installed nodejs, and fs errors (it says vm error)